# Keyboard combination notations - is there list?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notation

Wikipedia has a list of notations about the Control key:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key#Notation

Is there a resource that lists the different notations for combinations of other keys (and/or notations for "non-abc" keys)?

Examples of meanings [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) are not necessary.

Comment: great page, but what I'm looking for is a table of notations, not the outcomes. I'm trying to make myself aware of more notations so I won't be shocked when do something like opening some hypothetical .rc for an mc-fork made for osx (given that the fork uses some notation already known to mankind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ctrl

Wikipedia had this for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

```
^X      Traditional notation
C-x     Emacs notation
CTRL-X  Old Microsoft notation
Ctrl+X  New Microsoft notation
Ctrl/X  OpenVMS notation
```

I'm adding [[1](http://www.openvms.compaq.com/doc/73final/6489/6489pro_051.html)]:

```
Ctrl_N
Ctrl--N
```

Corresponding for <kbd>Alt</kbd>, excluding trivial ones that follow from above such as `Alt+X`, would be:

#### Alt

```
^[x
M-x
Mod1 x (seen in e.g. Fluxbox config)
```

#### "Windows logo" button

```
s-x
Win+X
Super+X
Mod4 x
```

---

...but compiling a full list is not possible (if someone wants to try here, feel free to edit my post). Your best bet is to use search engines to find the correct notation for your current application from case to case.

Comment: absolutely useful, thanks. I'll wait some time before deciding to accept it to see if any more information could emerge.

Comment: What notation "^[x" is? M-x must be emacs. EDIT - ah I just realized it's the traditional notation. my fault.

Comment: the exact problem with search engines is that often it's hard to find things like "^[x" with them (special symbols in general).

Comment: does [shift] has a notation? for things like Shift+Left or Ctrl+Shift+Down